# Query related to Searching

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There are four Text-box those are to be filled by user and searching have to be performed on the basis of those value. If user doesn't fill all the textboxes then **how can searching be performed in SQL**?

Comment: Basically I want to know the basic login how to perform searching on the basis of the combination of textbox  in which user can fill all the textboxes or leave any textbox blank

Answer (score 0):

You should use WHERE and LIKE in mysql: for example

```
SELECT * FROM table t 
where 
   t.name like 'textboxvalue' 
   or 
   t.value like '%textbox2value%' and so on.
```

You can do this in Stored Procedure with input arguments or in code.

Comment: the searching has to be done on the basis of combination of Textbox